# Show LDAP server PHP has chosen to connect to

Tags: php, ldap

PHP's [`ldap_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php) function allows you to "provide multiple LDAP-URIs separated by a space as one string". Is there any way to tell which server was selected upon doing an [`ldap_bind`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php)?

As a simplified example, if this was my setup:

```
$servers = 'ldaps://ad1.mydomain.com ldaps://ad2.mydomain.com ldaps://ad3.mydomain.com";
$ldap_conn = ldap_connect($servers) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
```

How can I tell which of the three servers was selected since `ldap_conn` only returns true/false?

I'm not looking to see which of the servers are online like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41075659/check-if-a-server-is-online) question, just which one was selected.

Comment: Not that I know of. But why is that of importance? The reason for this feature is to be able to provide multiple replicas and to be able to use the first one that answers. As all are "equal" there shouldn't be a reason to check which one was actually used...

Comment: BTW: ldap_connect returns a boolean that indicates whether the given string is plausible. As the docs state there is no connection done when calling ldap_connect. So at that stage you wouldn't even be able to say to which one a connection was made as no connection happened yet. The connection will be initiated on the first command that needs a connection (usually ldap_bind).

Comment: @heiglandreas Right, I know the ldap_connect is just a check and not an actual connection, and that happens with ldap_bind, I was just looking to see if there was a way to see which server PHP actually connects to for a variety of reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May not see the information without a little extra code but you can query each server to determine if it is there.

If you have a connection, you should, depending on the LDAP server Implementation query the rootDSE for the [dsaName](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/DsaName).

The dsaName is typically supported but the structure may vary from one vendor to another. 
I know it is supported by Microsoft Active Directory and directory and most LDAP server vendors ,

This cam up earlier "[Find out what load balanced Domain Controller LDAP is attempting to connect to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42455050/88122)?"